# Ajax validation with custom id in yii2

Tags: ajax, validation, yii2

I have a same field in foreach loop like below

```
foreach ( $subCategoryData as $k => $val) {
    <?= $form->field($model, 'sub_category', ['template' => '{input}'])->textInput(['maxlength' => 255, 'class' => 'form-control required section_name', 'name' => "Category[sub_category][$k][name]"]) ?>
} ?>
```

I have ajax validation with custom method it is working fine.

But it is Working with only first input. Because it has same ID.

But when I changed it with `'inputOptions' => ['id' => 'myCustomId']` and make it unique with below and my ajax validation is not called.

```
foreach ( $subCategoryData as $k => $val) {
    <?= $form->field($model, 'sub_category', ['template' => '{input}','inputOptions' => ['id' => "category-sub_category_".$k]])->textInput(['maxlength' => 255, 'class' => 'form-control required section_name', 'name' => "Category[sub_category][$k][name]"]) ?>
}
```

I have seen this solution here 
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7627

and also seen this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28460442/2286537

But nothing work
can anyone help me ?

Comment: I see in this link a possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738180/yii2-validation-rule-for-multiple-inputs-with-same-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is different from the posts you introduced.
You should use loadMultiple.

> Example:

```
if (\Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
    if (\yii\base\Model::loadMultiple($model,\Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        \Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        echo json_encode(ActiveForm::validateMultiple($model));
        \Yii::$app->end();
    }
}

if ( \yii\base\Model::loadMultiple($model, Yii::$app->request->post()) &&  \yii\base\Model::validateMultiple($model)) {
      foreach ($model as $models) {
          $models->save(false);
      }
```

in view:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
      'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
   ]);
```